# Unfortunately <app-name> has stopped

Tags: java, android, xml

I have written a code for an app that is supposed to be for a Virtual Campus tour. I have shared below the various files (3 class files) and 3 xml files and all have no errors in them.

The app has installed on the emulator successfully but throws up the error mentioned in the heading.

I am very new to android and to java so any help will be really appreciated!

Can anyone spot where I have gone wrong?

Code for one class by the name BuildingEdit

```
package com.example.udbuildingtour;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class BuildingEdit extends Activity {
    private EditText mNameText;
    private EditText mLatText;
    private EditText mLongiText;
    private Long mRowId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.building_edit);
        setTitle(R.string.edit_building);

        mNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mLatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        mLongiText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longi);

        Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

        mRowId = null;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String name = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME);
            String lat = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LAT);
            String longi = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LONGI);
            mRowId = extras.getLong(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_ID);

            if (name != null) {
                mNameText.setText(name);
            }
            if (lat != null) {
                mLatText.setText(lat);
            }
            if (longi != null) {
                mLongiText.setText(longi);
            }
        }

        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME, mNameText.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LAT, mLatText.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LONGI, mLongiText.getText().toString());
                if (mRowId != null) {
                    bundle.putLong(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_ID, mRowId);
                }

                Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }


    }
```

Code for class UDBuildingTour

```
package com.example.udbuildingtour;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class UDBuildingTour extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

    private BuildingsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private Cursor mBuildingsCursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.building_edit);


        mDbHelper = new BuildingsDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createBuilding();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteBuilding(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

     private void createBuilding() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, BuildingEdit.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
        }

     @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            Cursor c = mBuildingsCursor;
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, BuildingEdit.class);
            i.putExtra(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_ID, id);
            i.putExtra(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME, c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME)));
            i.putExtra(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LAT, c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LAT)));
            i.putExtra(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LONGI, c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LONGI)));
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            switch(requestCode) {
                case ACTIVITY_CREATE:
                    Long rowId = extras.getLong(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_ID);
                    String name = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME);
                    String lat = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LAT);
                    String longi = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LONGI);
                    mDbHelper.createBuilding(rowId, name, lat, longi);
                    fillData();
                    break;
                case ACTIVITY_EDIT:
                    Long Id = extras.getLong(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_ID);
                    if (Id != null) {
                        String editName = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME);
                        String editLat = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LAT);
                        String editLongi = extras.getString(BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_LONGI);
                        mDbHelper.updateBuilding(Id, editName, editLat, editLongi);
                    }
                    fillData();
                    break;
            }
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.udbuilding_tour, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void fillData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
        mBuildingsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllBuildings();
        startManagingCursor(mBuildingsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only BUILDINGNAME)
        String[] from = new String[]{BuildingsDbAdapter.KEY_BUILDINGNAME};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter building = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.buildings_row, mBuildingsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(building);


    }


}
```

Code for BuildingsDBAdapter

```
package com.example.udbuildingtour;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class BuildingsDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUILDINGNAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String KEY_LONGI = "longi";
    private static final String TAG = "BuildingsDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table buildings (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Buildings";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "UDBuildings";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public BuildingsDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }



    public BuildingsDbAdapter open() throws SQLException  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public boolean deleteBuilding(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }

    public long createBuilding(Long id, String name, String lat, String longi) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("UDBuildings.txt"));
            String s;

            while((s = in.readLine()) != null){

                String[] var = s.split(":");
                     //var[0]=ID,var[1]=Name etc etc
                initialValues.put(KEY_BUILDINGNAME, var[1]);
                initialValues.put(KEY_LAT, var[2]);
                initialValues.put(KEY_LONGI, var[3]);
                initialValues.put(KEY_ID, var[0]);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }

     /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all buildings in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all buildings
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllBuildings() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_BUILDINGNAME,
                KEY_LAT, KEY_LONGI}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the building that matches the given building id
     * 
     * @param id of building to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching building, if found
     * @throws SQLException if building could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchBuilding(long id) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID,
                    KEY_BUILDINGNAME, KEY_LAT, KEY_LONGI}, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the building using the details provided. The building to be updated is
     * specified using the id, and it is altered to use the name and lat, longi
     * values passed in
     * 
     * @param id of building to update
     * @param name value to set building name to
     * @param lat value to set building lat to
     * @param longi value to set building longi to
     * @return true if the building was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */


    public boolean updateBuilding(Long rowId, String editName, String editLat, String editLongi) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_BUILDINGNAME, editName);
        args.put(KEY_LAT, editLat);
        args.put(KEY_LONGI, editLongi);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

    }

}
```

xml code for building_edit

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="name" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/name" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="lat" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/lat" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="longi" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/longi" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/confirm" 
      android:text="confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

xml code for buildings_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

xml code for buildings_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="no_buildings"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

androidmanifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.udbuildingtour"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.udbuildingtour.UDBuildingTour"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity>       
        <activity android:name=".BuildingEdit"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the logcat output for the crash (which is almost certainly due to an uncaught exception). From Eclipse, you can see the logcat output by opening the Logcat view.

Comment: Also think about implementing logging, and using crash analytic software like Flurry or Crashlytics. It'll make this kind of stuff *so much easier* to deal with.

Comment: I don't always post questions to StackOverflow, but when I do, I post everything but the most relevant bit of information.

Comment: @TedHopp - i know this sounds weird ... but there are no messages on logcat for the error! i have tried to close the emulator and run the app multiple times to look for these messages so that i can present them to you , but each time the logcat window is blank! any suggestions?

Comment: If the logcat window is blank, Eclipse isn't correctly accessing the device. (This happens to me sometimes.) You should be seeing a lot of messages from the device, most of them routine (e.g., every garbage collection run). Open the Devices view and click on the emulator in the list of devices and then switch back to the logcat view. If you don't see the emulator listed, restart the adb from the Devices view menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and not this...

```
 android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

in your ListView

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1. The `UDBuildingTour` activity is not using `buildings_list` as the content view. As a result, there is no `ListView` and the base `ListActivity` will throw an exception when you call `setListAdapter(building);` in `fill_data`. In `onCreate()`, you should change this:

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.building_edit);
   ```

   to:

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.building_list);
   ```
2. As [@stir-fried points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638781/535871), the `android:id` attribute for the `ListView` in `buildings_list` should be `@android:id/list`, not `@+id/android:list` (which I'm surprised compiles). For a custom list activity layout, you need to use the predefined Android id for the `ListView`, not autogenerating your own id. Similarly, the empty-list view should have `android:id=@android:id/empty`, not `@+id/android:empty`.